# Simple way to replicate bloom (glow) effect in image using Matlab?

Tags: image-processing

I have some simulated images of light bulbs in Matlab. What I want to do is replicate the bloom (glow) effect on these images. The degree of the effect (i.e. how much the light bulbs bloom) should be controllable.

Is there any implemented function in Matlab Image Processing Toolbox help me to achieve this. Or is there any simple algorithm for this. I don't want a sophisticated algorithm since I don't require the bloom effect to be precisely replicated.

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Work in a linear gamma (intensity-linear) color space. Create a Gaussian blurred version of the image. I don't have MATLAB to try it, but it can be done using [`imgaussfilt`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html). Then add some of the blurred image to the original image, or mix the two images to taste.

[image: Simulated bloom]
*Figure 1. Bloom simulated in Gimp by adding to the image its Gaussian blurred copy at 31.5 % opacity.*

Comment: Nice! Do you know is this **the** method or just one of many methods?

Comment: @Fat32 https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20custom%20shaders is an example that at least someone does it this way. One could use more natural point spread functions than Gaussian + impulse. Gaussian blur is pretty cheap to calculate though because it is separable, and it can be approximated. There's some literature on human eye point spread functions.